# Android: Check a specific checkbox (I know the position!)

Tags: android, android-listview, position, android-checkbox

I have a listview with checkboxes. Now I want to check a specific checkbox (certain position). I am working on 3 days on this issue and I do not come to an end. Please help.

Comment: mate, I think you should post some code.

Comment: With no code, no-one can help.  I assume you've called `setChecked(true)` and invalidated the parent view?

Answer (score 1):

As you said that, you already know certain position of checkbox which you want to check. Follow this,

1. Go to your `getView()` method in adapter class.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final ViewHolder viewHolder;

       if(convertView==null)
       {
           viewHolder=new ViewHolder();    
           viewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myCHeckBox);
           convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
       }
       else
       {
           viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }   

       if (position == myCertainPosition) {
           viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);  
       } else {
           viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);  
       }
       return convertView;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank You very much, this works: The specific checkbox will be checked. But how can I do this outside the getView() method - by clicking a button outside the listview.